# macro throwing me error subscript out of range

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have two file of excel having same data only difference is colour in header.when I try to execute with this macro one file is executing with colour and without colour excel file throw me error on this subscript out of range.

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cnt As Long, newSh As Worksheet
Set sh = ActiveSheet
sh.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter  <------ this line I am getting issue
```

Comment: What does `MsgBox Sh.ListObjects.Count` return?

Comment: count is zero.but I have one row with data

Comment: Then you don't actually have a table (`ListObject`).

Comment: Sorry I did not understand which table you are talking about.I want to add screenshot of two excel both have same data.only difference is colour one is working fine and another not.I just want to add screen shot.where I can add the attachment

Comment: A screenshot won't make a difference, to be honest. The one that is not working is not actually a table. That is the answer.

Comment: can you please share me your email id if possible.I will send you both the excel you can also check both have same data

Comment: No can do, sorry. I'm telling you though, you *don't* have a table. If "count is zero," then you *don't* have a table.

Comment: which table you are talking about can you explain me so I can check.because data is same both file I copy paste.please explain me which table you are talking

Comment: Copy/paste doesn't necessarily mean that the new file has a table (`ListObject`).

Comment: Activesheet means..?here in macro used active sheet...?

Answer (score 0):

As BigBen correctly points out, `sh.ListObjects(1)` will trigger an error when `sh` does not have a table.

You can learn about tables here: [Overview of Excel Tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)

To fix the error, select the relevant data, then go to Insert > Table. If the data has headers, place a check mark in "My data has headers." Click OK.

Now the sheet has a table, and the macro should work.

Comment: ok thanks for reply but when I try this my excel sheet hanged and after few minutes excel not responding

Comment: select all data on the sheet, then go to Insert > Table. If the data has headers, place a check mark in "My data has headers." Click OK this value my excel hanged not responding .=$1:$1048576

Comment: yes its work but every time I need to   select the relevant data, then go to Insert > Table. If the data has headers, place a check mark in "My data has headers." Click OK.without this I can't run macro